# Compiler casts derived instance as parent abstract class

Tags: c++

I have a bug in a project I am making where I am trying to use abstract classes.
I have an abstract class defined as follows:

```cpp
class BoundingVolume: public Displayable{

public:

    virtual bool intersects(BoundingVolume const& bv) const noexcept = 0;

    virtual bool intersects(Sphere const& sp)const noexcept = 0;

    virtual bool intersects(AABB const& aabb) const noexcept= 0;

    virtual float getVolume() = 0;

    virtual std::tuple<std::vector<std::array<float,3>>, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>> &toMesh() = 0;
};
```

I am using it as a member of another class because in that class I don't know what derived class of it I want to use:

```
class Object{
public :
    explicit Object(std::vector<Point> const& vertices) noexcept;

    std::vector<Point> m_vertices;
    BoundingVolume *m_bounding_volume;
};
```

The code of my constructor for Object :

```
m_vertices = vertices

AABB aabb(points); // AABB is a derived class of BoundingVolume
auto aabb_pt = (AABB*) malloc(sizeof(AABB));
    *aabb_pt = aabb;

 m_bounding_volume = aabb_pt;
```

The problem is that when I construct an instance of Object and call `toMesh` on its BoundingVolume member, the program crashes (exit code 139). And while debugging it seems that it is because at the last line of my constructor the compiler makes a cast which does not allow it to understand later that `m_bounding_volume` is an instance of a derived class.
What am I doing wrong? Am I understanding everything correctly? What should be changed?

Comment: `auto aabb_pt = (AABB*) malloc(sizeof(AABB));` -- Why are you using `malloc`?  You didn't create any object at all on that line, so any usage of `aabb_pt` as-if you did create an object is undefined behavior.

Comment: `malloc` allocates memory, it does not create an object. Why do you use it here?

Comment: `m_bounding_volume = new AABB(points);`

Comment: Advice -- don't use `C` material or books if you want to write C++ code.  No C++ book I know of would show the usage of `malloc`, unless you are using `placement-new`.

Comment: I was trying to use `malloc` as I would in C to allocate the storage needed for the class and then put the right values to the pointed address. This is not how one should do apparently. Thank you for your answers, they solved my issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `malloc` to allocate memory for this class. In C++, objects might need additional logic to construct that isn't encapsulated by malloc, and this is especially, extremely true for objects that have inheritance, since [in most common implementations] the compiler has to do hidden work to construct the extra member data required to hold its type information.

In C++, you should be using the `new` keyword instead:

```
m_vertices = vertices

AABB aabb(points); // AABB is a derived class of BoundingVolume
auto aabb_pt = new AABB(aabb); //Assuming that you do intend to allocate a copy of aabb, and not merely point to it
//If you just wanted a pointer to aabb, this would be more appropriate
//auto aabb_pt = &aabb;

 m_bounding_volume = aabb_pt;
```

It's also good practice in C++ to prefer using smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr`, as these allow you to express ownership semantics and will help prevent these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Given that the code is in the constructor of the class with the `m_bounding_volume` member, it is probably meant to be just `m_bounding_volume = new AABB(points);` Storing a pointer to the local variable would result in a dangling pointer.

Comment: @user17732522 I can't see the full scope of their code. It can sometimes be appropriate to pass pointers to scope-allocated objects if the programmer knows the object receiving the pointer will also be destroyed before it leaves scope. There is a potential issue with dangling pointers because the ownership semantics of their code is completely unspecified, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It solved the issue. As you understood, I am not entirely used to c++ yet so it was just a dumb mistake. Thank you again